# Solid cube painted and cut into $64$ smaller cubes question

Tags: probability

A solid cube, painted all around, is cut into $64$ identical cubes. One of these
cubes is chosen at random and rolled. What is the probability that none of the five faces showing is painted?

My solution: There is a $\frac{1}{64}$
probability of choosing any one of the small cubes. Since none of the
five visible faces is painted, the chosen cube either has no painted faces or has one
painted face, which is out of sight (with probability of the other non painted faces being shown is $\frac{5}{6}$
). There are $2
×
2
×
2 = 8$ small
cubes with no painted faces (from the middle of the large cube), and $6
×
4 = 24$
with one painted face (four from each of the six large faces). The probability of none of the five faces shown is painted is therefore: $$\frac{8}{64}.1+\frac{24}{64}.\frac{5}{6} = \frac{7}{16}$$

However, when I checked the memo, it said the answer was $\frac{3}{16}$. How is this possible? Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 3):

A cube with one painted face has to have its painted face out of sight. So the face that is oriented downward has to be the painted one. This has prob 1/6, not 5/6.

Comment: I still cannot wrap my head around this concept, because The other 5 faces are not painted, so $\frac{5}{6}$ of the cube is not painted? Why $\frac{1}{6}$? I see that as only $\frac{1}{6}$ of the cube is NOT painted.

Comment: A cube with one side painted won't always land the 'right' way. Think about the face that touches the table--it's equally likely to be any of the six faces, but only one of these six faces (the painted one) will yield the outcome that we are seeking. Conclude that a one-side-painted cube will meet our requirements only 1/6 of the time, whereas a totally unpainted cube will meet our requirements all the time.