# Probability with cubes

Tags: probability

A cube of with dimensions $k \times k \times k$ has its outside painted. It is then cut into $k^3$ smaller cubes, the smaller cubes are put into a bag. One of the smaller cubes is then thrown. What is the probability that it lands with the painted side facing up?

Comment: Welcome to Math StackExchange! What have you tried so far?

Comment: You can do this!  HINT: how many little cubes end up with no sides being painted? How many with 1? 2? etc.

Comment: $k\times k\times k=k^3$ is $\color{red}{\texttt{not}}$ an area. Please make an edit.

Comment: Hint : it is a two-stage process : a) choice of a cube b) throw of this cube.

Comment: a $k^3$ cube is cut into $k^3$ _smaller_ cubes?

Comment: Hint: Imagine that the original big cube is turned in such a way that it shares the final orientation of the thrown small cube. The visible face (of the small cube) is  painted if and only if the small cube is from the top floor (in the current orientation of the big cube). This holds obviously with probability $1/k$.

Answer (score 3):

The $k^3$ little cubes have $6k^3$ faces in all. Of these $6k^2$ are painted, so the probability one gets a painted face on top is
$(6k^2)/(6k^3)=\cdots$.

Answer (score 1):

The solution given by @Lord Shark the Unknown is especially clever and short. (I confess I didn't agree with it at first). Here is a much longer proof that can serve as a guideline in similar but not identical cases.

Consider the experience as a two-stage process :

- A cube is chosen.
- Then, this cube is thrown.

The probability of a global success is equivalent to a success at the two stages :

$$\tag{1} P(A \cap B) = P(A) \times P(B|A)$$

Where events $A$ = the cube is painted on at least one face and $B$ = the upper face is colored.

(1) can be extended in this way:

$$\tag{2}\dfrac{C}{k^3} \times \left(\frac16 \times \frac{6(k-2)^2}{C}+\frac26 \times \frac{12(k-2)}{C}+\frac36 \times \frac{8}{C} \right) \ = \ \dfrac{6k^2}{6k^3}=\dfrac{1}{k}$$

(where $C$ is the number of painted cubes ; we don't need its explicit value $k^3-(k-2)^3$).

We find back the expression given by Lord Shark.

Up to you for a detailed understanding of formula (2) : in particular, why coefficients $6, 12, 8$ and corresponding factors  $\frac16, \frac26, \frac36 $ ?

Comment: Connected : (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1204697)